# Contiki OS RPL Protocol : Multicast to specific Group of node

Tags: networking, multicast, contiki

Actually I am trying to implement Multicasting to specific group of node in the contiki OS using RPL protocol. I am able to send the multicast to all available nodes but I am unable to form the group of node and send packet to only to the group of node. So I wanted to know how to create group in rpl in contiki OS ? Then how do I send packet to specific group only ?

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation of Contiki-2.6 does not forward multicast packets. Have a look at this link https://github.com/g-oikonomou/contiki-sensinode/tree/uip6-mcast and for more details into this [Link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6197494) paper.